# How to add background image to Lightning component Body from static resource?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, css

I'm trying to access the body tag but it seems it's not possible using **document.getElementsByTagName(*tagName*)** and **$A.util.addClass**, I want to add a background image, I was trying to do it in the component's style file 
but couldn't make it work.

Any ideas or suggestions to follow, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `.THIS` class in the Lightning Component style file. `.THIS` refers to the whole lightning component.

**Step 1:**

Get the url of the static resource that is similar to this format `resource/#############/resourceName`.

You can get this simply by adding the static resource reference in Lightning Component Markup(Component File) - `{!$Resource.imageResourceName}`
[image]

Once you run the component - it will show the URL of the static resource.
[image]

**Step 2:**

Just grab the URL that you got in step one and add it in the `.THIS` class, something like this:

```
.THIS{
background-image: url('/resource/1556180826000/Arunachala_pic') !important; 
}
```

And that's it!

[image]

I hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add details in cmp and js file as below example. Before you do, upload your image in static resource and get the name of image.

```
cmp :

<aura:component >
    <aura:attribute name="backgroundImageURL" type="String"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>   
    <div style="{!'position: relative; height: 120vh; background:' + v.backgroundColor + ' url(' + v.backgroundImageURL +') no-repeat;background-position: center;background-size: cover;'}">       
    </div>   
</aura:component>
```

```
js :

({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        var url = $A.get('$Resource.nameofyourimagefromstaticresource');
        component.set('v.backgroundImageURL', url);
    }  
})
```